# Tabulary suppress frame border

Tags: tabulary

I'm using Python Sphinx to generate my manuals which contains a variety of different tables. In some case I need to adjust a table, so that it doesn't show the frame any longer. Python Sphinx outputs are `tabulary` environments from the package `tabulary`.

So I tried by omitting the `|` in the environment:

```
\begin{tabulary}{ccc}
...
\end{tabulary}
```

Still there are lines at the top, at the bottom and eventually in between. What I'm missing here?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting code fragments it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. It is really difficult to help you without more information. This said, you probably just need to remove some `\hline` commands from the table.

Comment: Hello, thanks for this advice. It is a bit hard for me to give a full minimal example, as we are talking about a generated TeX file, rather than a TeX file, that I wrote on my own. Still I'll try to revise my question.

Comment: It's a bit hard to answer without knowing what you are doing:) Just cut one of the generated files down to a MWE that contains a small tabular environment exhibiting the problem.

Comment: You were right. It is really the `\hline`, that I have to remove. The problem is not so much a TeX problem as I thought beforehand. I have to configure Sphinx I a way, such that either the generation of `\hline` is suppressed or I need to redefine `\hline` so such it will not draw a line any longer.

Comment: If you are happy to disable `\hline` throughout your document then, for the latter, just add `\let\hline\relax` to your preamble. You can automate this using the `--latex-preamble=...` option to `rst2latex.py`

Comment: I already found a simple solution for my problem, that seems to work together with Sphinx.  Wrapping my table with `\begingroup\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0pt} [TABLE] \endgroup` seems to be a clumsy, but workable approach. I only need to temporarily deactivate the frames.